# Using "tee" to selectively log Ubuntu terminal output?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, logging, tee

I need to log terminal output. But I only need some outputs which starts with a keyword (say starts with "error"). I use something similar to:

```
ls | tee "log.txt"
```

In this example command I do not want to log everything the temrinal displays. Only say if I found an output that starts with "De". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your shell is `bash`, you can turn the output of `tee` into the input for `grep` with process substitution. For instance, when filtering the output of `ls` for lines that start with "De" into `log.txt`, the command would be:

```
ls |tee >(grep ^De >| log.txt)
```